# JSON data with double quotes

Tags: json

I am getting data from api call which contains double quotes. for example `data = '{"firstName":""John""}'`

how to parse this data into json.
 expected-output:`result = JSON.parse(data)` and `result.firstname` should give output as `"John"` not `John`

Comment: This is an invalid JSON string

Comment: Please specify your conditions. In wich language do you code? In wich conditions are the data use.

Comment: I code in react. I need to retrieve firstname from api response. JSON.parse(data) is giving error

Comment: *"JSON.parse(data) is giving error"* and the error is... ?

Comment: ```Unexpected token J in JSON at position 15```

Answer (score 1):

As @Cid points out, that is invalid JSON.

You will need to sanitize it first:-

```
var json = data.replace(/""/g, '"');

var x = JSON.parse(json);
```

If you want to keep the inner quotes, you'll need to use something like this:-

```
var json = data.replace(/(\".*\":)\"\"(.*)\"\"/g, '$1 "\\"$2\\""');

var x = JSON.parse(json);
```

However, you may need to fiddle with the regex if it conflicts with other parameters.

You can review the regex above at https://regex101.com/ to get an explanation of how the regex matches:-

```
/(\".*\":)\"\"(.*)\"\"/g

  1st Capturing Group (\".*\":)
    \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
    .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
      * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
    : matches the character : literally (case sensitive)

  \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
  \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)

  2nd Capturing Group (.*)
    .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
      * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

  \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
  \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)

Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

The `$1` and `$2` in the replacement text correspond to the capture groups in the regex. See [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for details.

Comment: I want quotes in output. I have edited question. Please check

Comment: @AnkithaVaddeti, see my edit for a basic solution/starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Try With this

```
var json = '{"firstName":""John""}';       //Let's say you got this
json = json.replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g,"$1:");  //This will remove all the quotes
json;
```